# iOS 7 CFNetwork crash

Tags: ios, crash, cfnetwork

My application crashing on iOS 7 in com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader thread with this crash log:

```
Crashed: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2fb2e79e CFArrayGetCount + 5
1  CFNetwork                      0x2f7fcc03 HTTPConnectionCacheEntry::notifyNextProtocolOfOpenConnection(NetConnection*, unsigned char) + 158
2  CFNetwork                      0x2f7fcc03 HTTPConnectionCacheEntry::notifyNextProtocolOfOpenConnection(NetConnection*, unsigned char) + 158
3  CFNetwork                      0x2f8084df NetConnection::responseIsComplete(void*) + 162
4  CFNetwork                      0x2f808405 HTTPNetStreamInfo::sendStreamIsComplete() + 48
5  CFNetwork                      0x2f805311 HTTPNetConnection::responseStreamCallback(void*, __CoreReadStream*, unsigned long) + 308
6  CFNetwork                      0x2f8051c1 NetConnection::connectionResponse(__CoreReadStream*, unsigned long) + 116
7  CFNetwork                      0x2f7e9391 CoreReadStreamClient::coreStreamEventsAvailable(unsigned long) + 36
8  CFNetwork                      0x2f890497 CoreStreamBase::_callClientNow(CoreStreamClient*) + 42
9  CFNetwork                      0x2f7e912f CoreStreamBase::_streamSetEventAndScheduleDelivery(unsigned long, unsigned char) + 122
10 CFNetwork                      0x2f7e8fd7 CoreStreamBase::_streamInterface_SignalEvent(unsigned long, CFStreamError const*) + 34
11 CFNetwork                      0x2f8041a3 HTTPReadFilter::socketReadStreamCallback(unsigned long) + 570
12 CFNetwork                      0x2f803f4b HTTPReadFilter::_httpRdFilterStreamCallBack(__CoreReadStream*, unsigned long, void*) + 70
13 CFNetwork                      0x2f7e9391 CoreReadStreamClient::coreStreamEventsAvailable(unsigned long) + 36
14 CFNetwork                      0x2f890497 CoreStreamBase::_callClientNow(CoreStreamClient*) + 42
15 CFNetwork                      0x2f7e912f CoreStreamBase::_streamSetEventAndScheduleDelivery(unsigned long, unsigned char) + 122
16 CFNetwork                      0x2f7e8fd7 CoreStreamBase::_streamInterface_SignalEvent(unsigned long, CFStreamError const*) + 34
17 CFNetwork                      0x2f7e8f77 SocketStream::dispatchSignalFromSocketCallbackUnlocked(SocketStreamSignalHolder*) + 54
18 CFNetwork                      0x2f7e8a09 SocketStream::socketCallback(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*) + 144
19 CFNetwork                      0x2f7e8947 SocketStream::_SocketCallBack_stream(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*, void*) + 58
20 CoreFoundation                 0x2fbc83c3 __CFSocketPerformV0 + 578
21 CoreFoundation                 0x2fbc620b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
22 CoreFoundation                 0x2fbc5761 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340
23 CoreFoundation                 0x2fbc3ecf __CFRunLoopRun + 622
24 CoreFoundation                 0x2fb2eebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
25 CoreFoundation                 0x2fb2eca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
26 Foundation                     0x3056f087 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 318
27 Foundation                     0x305e4a5f __NSThread__main__ + 1062
28 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a9d7919 _pthread_body + 140
29 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a9d788b _pthread_start + 102
30 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a9d5aa4 thread_start + 8
```

There is some info about crash on AFNetworking github page (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3003), but they closed it and pointed to fabric(https://twittercommunity.com/t/crashes-on-ios-7-after-updating-to-3-3-4/54693/15).

But disabling nor AFNetworking nor Fabric not helped me.

I tried to migrate to NSURLSession, but it did not help.

I've figured out that application crashing more if there is more POST requests. Disabling POST requests seems to eliminate crash completely.

I do not know where to dig further. Maybe someone has come across this. I will be glad to any help!